# Setting a custom attribute directive in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying to set a costume attribute directive to an input but I couldn't find the way to do it.

My directive is the following

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[disable-paste]'
})
export class DisablePaste {
    constructor(private _elementRef:ElementRef) {
        this._elementRef.nativeElement.onpaste = (e:any) => {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

If I just put the directive by its own in the input, it works. But when I try to use it "conditionally" it doesn't.
I tried all these:

```
<input [disable-paste]="doNotAllowPaste" ... />
<input disable-paste="doNotAllowPaste" ... />
<input [attr.disable-paste]="doNotAllowPaste" ... />
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need an input property in order to conditionally execute your logic, whenever the input property value changes:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[disable-paste]'
})
export class DisablePaste {
  @Input('disable-paste') disablePaste:boolean;

  constructor(private _elementRef:ElementRef) {}
  ngOnChanges() {
    if(this.disablePaste) {
      this._elementRef.nativeElement.onpaste = (e:any) => {
         e.preventDefault();
      }
    } else {
      this._elementRef.nativeElement.onpaste = null; 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You coulsd try this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[disable-paste]'
})
export class DisablePaste {
  @Input('disable-paste')
  disablePaste:any;

  constructor(private _elementRef:ElementRef) {
    this._elementRef.nativeElement.onpaste = (e:any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

If you use `[...]`, you will get an object corresponding to the evaluation of the specified expression. Without them, a string value.

Comment: This is a good alternative, but I wanted to know if there was a way of conditionally render that directive without having to add an input to it.

Comment: Just a silly question: why don't apply the directive if you don't have the behavior. The directive contains several things. Just try to understand better your issue ;-) Angular2 commonly mixes another attribute to disable it. For example: `selector: 'form:not([ngNoForm]):not([ngFormModel]),ngForm,[ngForm]'`. See https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/ng_form.ts#L81.